# installing npm to create react app using node

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

[image]

[image]

I am trying to create a react app but i get stuck here can not find the way. kindly help me.

Comment: Looks like you don't have node installed in your machine . You need node to install CRA .

Answer (score 0):

First install node
[download node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

then run  `npx create-react-app my-app`

also path must be

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

not

```
C:\Program Files\node.js     // you have put this in the path
```